# get an array of all categories with details in Magento

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I want to be able to call through the API to get an array of all the categories with the details like the URL key.  That goal in the end will be an array like this

```
$massage_cats=array(
    array("entity_id"=>78,
          "name"=>"Massage Oils and Tools",
          "url_key"=>"massage-oils-and-tools",
          "url_path"=>"essential-accessories/massage-oils-and-tools.html"),
    array("entity_id"=>79,
          "name"=>"Massage Oils",
          "url_key"=>"massage-oils",
          "url_path"=>"essential-accessories/massage-oils-and-tools/massage-oils.html")
);
```

So I would want to call out something like

```
$massage_cats= array();
$allcats = Mage::getModel('catalog/cats?')->loadAll();
    foreach($allcats $k=>$item){
        array_push($massage_cats,$item->loadDetails());
    }
```

I know that is totally made up and not real to the API but that is basically the goal. I do need the output as I showed it.  Ideas on the code to achieve the need?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This will get your values.  You can build your array however you like from here.

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('id')
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
->addAttributeToSelect('url')
->addAttributeToSelect('is_active');

foreach ($categories as $category)
{
    if ($category->getIsActive()) { // Only pull Active categories
        $entity_id = $category->getId();
        $name = $category->getName();
        $url_key = $category->getUrlKey();
        $url_path = $category->getUrl();
    }
}
```

`EDIT`

I adapted this from a post on [MagentoCommerce.com](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/24947/).  You can use this instead:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$tree = $category->getTreeModel();
$tree->load();
$ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
if ($ids){
    foreach ($ids as $id){
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $cat->load($id);

        $entity_id = $cat->getId();
        $name = $cat->getName();
        $url_key = $cat->getUrlKey();
        $url_path = $cat->getUrlPath();
    }
}
```

Comment: So darn close.. $url_path = $category->getUrl();  is not the url ie: where I should have had essential-accessories/massage-oils-and-tools.html I had http://domain.com/importScript.php/essential-accessories/massage-oils-and-tools.html and or even http://domain.com/importScript.php/catalog/category/view/s/in-the-shower/id/91/

Comment: Ah, try `$url_path = $category->getUrlPath();`

Comment: Was one of the first things I tried but I got "/massage-oils-and-tools"  where I should have gotten "essential-accessories/massage-oils-and-tools" for the cat "Massage Oils and Tools" with the parent "Essential Accessories" ..

Comment: Using either of normal collection or tree collection, it always fetches repeated categories, for eg. if a parent category "coffee" then it fetches, many times instead of once.

Answer (score 2):

HERE I WROTE FUNCTION UPTO THREE LEVELS RETURN IN ARRAY FORMAT

> **$array=hpCat(2,3); //categoryID,Sublevel upto three level**
>
> **print_r($array);**

```
<?php     

function hpCat($id,$level=0){
    if(!empty($id)){
        $level=empty($level)?0:$level;
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
        $levelOneItems = $category->getChildrenCategories();
        if (count($levelOneItems) > 0){
            $array=hpCatDetails($category);
            if($level>=1):
                $i=0;
                foreach($levelOneItems as $levelOneItem){ 
                    $array['sub'][$i]=hpCatDetails($levelOneItem);    
                    $leveltwoItems=$levelOneItem->getChildrenCategories();
                    if (count($leveltwoItems) > 0){
                        if($level>=2):
                            $j=0;
                            foreach($leveltwoItems as $leveltwoItem){     
                                $array['sub'][$i]['sub'][$j]=hpCatDetails($leveltwoItem);
                                $levelthreeItems=$leveltwoItem->getChildrenCategories();
                                if (count($levelthreeItems) > 0){
                                    if($level>=3):
                                    $k=0;
                                    foreach($levelthreeItems as $levelthreeItem){     
                                        $array['sub'][$i]['sub'][$j]['sub'][$k]=hpCatDetails($levelthreeItem);
                                        $k++;
                                    }  
                                    endif;
                                }
                                $j++;
                            }  
                        endif;
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
            endif;
        }
        return $array;
    }
    return array();
}
function hpCatDetails($cat){
    return array('name'=>$cat->getName());
}

$array=hpCat(2,3);//categoryID,Sublevel upto three level
echo '<pre>';print_r($array);die();


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the people looking for MySQL query to fetch all Magento categories.

```
SELECT
    e.entity_id AS id,
    e.parent_id,
    e.path,
    e.`level`,

IF (
    at_name.value_id > 0,
    at_name.
VALUE
    ,
    at_name_default.
VALUE

) AS `name`
FROM
    `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `at_name_default` ON (
    `at_name_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`
)
AND (
    `at_name_default`.`attribute_id` = '41'
)
LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `at_name` ON (
    `at_name`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`
)
AND (
    `at_name`.`attribute_id` = '41'
)
```

Comment: Awesome! that did the trick for me to get selected attribute values faster.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function to make it :

```
 private function __categoriesTree($id = 2) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');

    $_category = $category->load($id);
    $details = new stdClass();
    list($details->id, $details->name, $details->urlKey, $details->level, $details->children) = [
        $_category->getId(),
        $_category->getName(),
        $_category->getUrlKey(),
        $_category->getLevel(),
        []
    ];

    foreach (array_filter(explode(',', $_category->getChildren())) as $childId) {
        $details->children[] = $this->__categoriesTree($childId);
    }
    if (count($details->children) === 0) {
        unset($details->children);
    }
    return $details;
}
```

And

```
$categoriesTree=  $this->categoriesTree()
```

I prefer to use objects than arrays to model a node but you can easily replace.